# Principal ultrafilter and free filter

Tags: general-topology, filters

I have 2 questions about filter and (ultra-)filters:

1. Which relations are there between free filter, principal filter, ultrafilter, Frechet filter, and co-finite filter?
2. If a filter is free, does it imply that it is a principal ultrafilter?

Comment: You probably wanted to write "ultrafilter" instead of "uttra-filter". I guess you meant Fréchet filter not frecheh.

Comment: is not important that our space is finite or infinite?

Comment: All [ultrafilters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on a finite set are principal.

Answer (score 6):

A filter $\mathcal F$ is called [free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_filter) if $\bigcap \mathcal F=\emptyset$. <s>Filter, which is not free is called [principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_filter). Hence every filter is either free or principal and the same is true for ultrafilters.</s><sup>1</sup>

A [principal filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_filter) is a filter consisting of supersets of some fixed set. It is clear that a filter cannot be at the same time free and principal.

Principal *ultra*filters are very simple; any principal ultrafilter has the form
$$\mathcal F_a=\{A\subseteq X; a\in A\}$$
for some $a\in X$.

To show the existence of free ultrafilters, some form of Axiom of Choice is needed. The proof is often based on [ultrafilter lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter_lemma).

[Fréchet filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_filter) (a.k.a. cofinite filter) on a set $X$ is the filter consisting of all cofinite set, i.e., it is equal to
$$\mathcal F_{F}=\{A\subseteq X; X\setminus A\text{ is finite}\}.$$ 
An ultrafilter is free if and only if it contains the Fréchet filter.

---

<sup>1</sup> [It was pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725622/free-filter-on-wikipedia) that this is not usual meaning of the term *principal filter*. I was using "principal" and "non-free" as equivalent, it seems that they are not. (However, this usage is still correct for *ultrafilters*.)

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a free ultrafilter is one that is not principal. So any ultrafilter is either principal or free, and never both. The Frechet filter is a filter, not an ultrafilter.